# How to make summation from 0 to infinity in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math
k = 0
def factorial(k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return k * factorial(k - 1)


formula = (((factorial(4 * k)) * (1103 + 26390 * k)) / ((factorial(k) ** 4)) * (396 ** (4 * k)))

    while k > (1e − 15):
        for k in range ():
        if k == 0:
            return k
        else:
            return k + formula
        print(summation(k, formula))

value_wanted = ((2* math.sqrt(2)) / 9801) * summation(k)
print('1/pi equals' , value_wanted )
```

This is a code where it tries to make a formula that approximates the value of pi. It gives me an error in the line 'while k > 1e - 15 ' , and I don't know why. I want the code to return the sum of the formula I wrote in the formula variable, with each time changing the k value by 1 until the last term is less than 1e - 15.

Comment: What error? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve the question. Also note that indentation matters in python, and yours is way off.

Comment: What editor are you using? You get `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier` because the minus sign in `(1e−15)` is not a plain hyphen, but unicode char MINUS SIGN; `unicodedata.name('−')` will tell you this.

Comment: please fix your indentation

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a range to infinity - 
To keep the computer counting on and on, you could use a while loop:

```
k = 0
while True:
    k += 1
    ...
```

However, as you can see, this code has the downside it will  never end, since the computer will be busy counting on and on:
normal numeric methods can't count to "infinity" -  you should take a look on the math concepts of infinity before proceeding with your experiments.

If you want numeric calculations, just choose a "big enough" number. For an algebraic resolution which can_ take infinity into account , check the [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) package.